# Juniper SRX300 Maximum BGP routes

Tags: juniper, bgp, srx

I've got a Juniper SRX300 which i'm using to connect to 2 BGP peers. The documentation i've read says this SRX only supports 300,000 BGP routes, so for each peer I created an import policy (based on communities) to only accept my peers customer routes and not the full table. These are roughly 2k routes for peer 1 and 3k routes for peer 2.

It all works fine, however it seems that although only the filtered routes are used the entire table is being stored. For example if I do this I get details of any route from the full table(s)

show route 1.1.1.1 hidden detail

inet.0: 726648 destinations, 726650 routes (3915 active, 0 holddown, 722735 hidden)

```
1.1.1.0/24 (1 entry, 0 announced)
     BGP                 /-101
            Next hop type: Router, Next hop index: 1333
            Address: 0x1990fe0
            Next-hop reference count: 728538
            Source: X.X.X.X
            Next hop: X.X.X.X via ge-0/0/6.0, selected
            Session Id: 0x0
            State: <Hidden Ext>
            Local AS: XXXXX Peer AS: XXXXX
            Age: 4:40:08
            Validation State: unverified
            Task: BGP_XXXXX.X.X.X.X
            AS path: XXXXX 13335 I
            Aggregator: XXXXX X.X.X.X
            Communities: XXXXX:XX XXXXX:XXX XXXXX:XXXX XXXXX:XXXX
            Localpref: 100
            Router ID: X.X.X.X
            Hidden reason: rejected by import policy
```

So my question was, is the 300k limit only on active routes? Or stored but hidden routes as well?

Thanks

Comment: Though this question is probably on topic here you might have a better chance of getting an answer on [networkengineering.se].